# Приватный сервер из файлов браузерной игры

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Сегодня мой друг сделал приватный сервер из одной браузерной игры под названием starve.io. Я хочу повторить его успех и сделать свой со своим модом, но не имею опыта в этом деле.

Чтобы подключится к его серверу нужно в консоле сайта ввести следующие тсроки: `javascript:(function(){ $.get("https://mf2.starveserver.tk/info" ) .done(function( data ) { i7.Gv[0].unshift(data); i7.oL(0); $(".md-select").click(); $(".md-select ul li")[1].click() }) .fail(function(data) { alert("Can't connect to server") }); })();` то у вас появится кнопка что бы начать играть. Обьясните как он это сделал. Я новенький, поэтому не судите строго.